3D Surfaces in Asymptote Help
I am trying to make this figure in asymptote. The curve has the equation x^2+y^3/3-z^2=0 with the restriction x^2+y^2+z^2=1 so the points belong to the unit sphere.
I can plot this curve on a sphere, but I have trouble splitting the surface of the sphere in the two regions. I would like to receive some help with drawing this diagram.
Essentially, I have to draw the surface x^2+y^3/3-z^2>=0 with the restriction x^2+y^2+z^2=1 (this being one of the halves). My main idea was to use smoothcontour3 somehow but I am a complete begginer and I didn't find anything satisfactory online. I have this code:
settings.render=16;
settings.prc=false;
size(10cm);

import smoothcontour3;

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(2,5,4));

real f(real x, real y, real z) {
    return x^2 + y^3/3 - z^2;
}

draw(implicitsurface(f, (-2,-2,-2), (2,2,2), overlapedges=true),
     surfacepen=material(gray(0.8)));

I am more or less stuck. I'd appreciate any help with drawing this!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Edited; I need help with the code itself.
